# Функция equal_range и лямбда выражения

Tags: c++, алгоритм, лямбда-выражение

Есть необходимость найти в массиве строк диапазон строк, которые начинаются на определенную букву. Так как по умолчанию `string` и `char` не сравниваются, то пишем соответствующие функции сравнения. Как я понял их нужно две, так как с одной не работает. Вписываю их в структуру и получается что-то вроде:

```
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const std::string &a, char b) {return a[0] < b;};
    bool operator()(char b, const std::string &a) {return b < a[0];};
}

std::equal_range(arr.begin(), arr.end(), pref, Comp{});
```

Мой вопрос вот в чем: а можно ли вместо этой структуры использовать лямбда-выражение?

Comment: Просто не сравнивайте с символом, а сравниваете со строкой состоящийся из одного символа или начинающийся с этого символа  :   bool operator()(const std::string &a, const string  &b) {return a[0] == b[0];}

Comment: Эх, опять вы `==` поставили - нужно именно `<`. Но идею я понял: я уже так сделал

Comment: а мне интересно почему именно  < нужно?

Comment: Как я понимаю, алгоритм использует двоичный поиск и ему "нужно знать" в какую сторону двигаться. К тому же я проверял что будет если ставить равно - не работает как пологается.

Comment: я опять ошибся просто, нужно  возвращать истину при неравенстве,  а именно:  return a[0] != b[0]; Тогда все прекрасно будет работать.  Альгоритм  действительно  делит диапазон на две части, но  это не влияет на работу компаратора, который просто возвращает true  или  false.  Сравнение на меньше  происходит по умолчанию(без компаратора)

Comment: не все так просто))) используя ваш вариант можно построить рабочий код, который покажет первое и последнее вхождение необходимых элементов... но! А если таких элементов нет? Что покажет ваш код? По умолчанию данный алгоритм должен выводить позицию куда можно вставить искомый элемент, а что выведет ваш вариант?

Comment: вот теперь дошли до истины. Все верно,  такой недостаток при моем варианте присутствует.  Кому то эти комментарии будут полезны, что является важным  фактором, потому я отмечу ваш вопрос как полезный, и спасибо за вашу активность и адекватность

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот, например:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<string> v{"acv","asd","bcd","bsd","bxy","vsd","zxy" };

    auto [b,e] = equal_range(v.begin(),v.end(),'b',
                             [](auto x, auto y)
                             {
                                 if constexpr (sizeof(x) == 1)
                                 {
                                     return x < y[0];
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     return x[0] < y;
                                 }
                             });

    for(auto i = b; i != e; ++i)
        cout << *i << endl;

}
```

Можно воспользоваться более серьезной проверкой `is_same`, я взял что попроще :)